# Import a P12 certificate into a NSS database (with an alias)

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, openssl, curl, nss

Here´s the deal... I have a personal P12 certificate generated by a certificate authority.

I want to use it with CURL to access a protected URL. 
If CURL on CENTOS was compiled with openssl, I should only convert it to PEM format and provide that file to CURL (tested on UBUNTU and working).

The problem is that my curl is compiled with NSS. So, after googling a while, I found that I need to generate a NSS database and importing the cert into this database. After that I should be able to call curl passing an alias to it, and access my URL.

( as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265100/curl-command-unable-to-load-client-cert-8018 )

But I cant find a way to provide an ALIAS to my key. So curl wont find my imported key.

Calling curl gives me:

```
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/var/nss
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
* Server certificate:
```

After a little research, I end up with 2 options:
- try to import (or regenerate) this database (or p12) with an nickname (cant find how to do it)
- or try to replace my curl and php_curl (I´ll need that later on) with one compiled with openssl (cant find a proper repository with both packages)

Any ideas??